# Can I configure number of brokers in Confluent Kafka Cloud with basic endition?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

Because of budget issue, I personally am using Confluent Cloud basic edition which is free.

Is there any way to setup number of kafka brokers on my own?

I could not find anything related on confluent cloud web UI settings.

Does only Dedicated edition support such settings? I cannot afford that much right now.

Or is it possible to configure cluster settings (like number of brokers etc)

on my local terminal CLI?

Comment: _is it possible to configure cluster settings (like number of brokers etc) on my local terminal CLI?_ - Sure, you can run Kafka locally, using as many brokers as you need, but that wouldn't be in the cloud

Comment: then How does Confluent Cloud deals with instant increase of message tps? Does confluent cloud automatically scale out its cluster size? even if its basic edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluent Cloud provides a "serverless" experience, and you cannot configure the number of brokers.

Comment: then does serverless confluent cloud will automatically manages against increase of record tps? I guess one of pros of using Kafka is it can elastically handles sudden explosions of messages

Comment: Confluent Cloud is consumption based and there is a "logical" unit called CKU that provides some level of resources. Compare the different cluster types for details: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/clusters/cluster-types.html -- Given that Confluent Cloud is multi-tenant, you cannot really map CKUs to brokers.

Comment: I guess CKU does job what I asked (elastically handles sudden explosions of messages) according to the documents you posted with in comment. Then does basic edition which I am using now also supports autoscaling via CKU?

Comment: Auto-scaling is not available in Confluent Cloud. -- I don't know if basic clusters would qualify for this feature or not.